# Ayuda con la logica de un query para MySQLi

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Saludos chicos tengo la siguiente sentencia:

```
$query = "SELECT * 
FROM pedidos  
WHERE usuario = '$usua
AND status_pedido = 'ESPERANDO' ";
```

asi como esta perfectamente funciona pero quisiera que tambien seleccione si se cumple la condicion status_pedido = 'APROBADO'

he intentado colocando el condicional

```
OR status_pedido = 'APROBADO'
```

Pero no me da resultados aun cuando si existe un dato con status_pedido = 'ESPERANDO' o 'APROBADO'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prueba usando la expresión [IN](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/in-function.php) de esta manera:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM pedidos  
WHERE usuario = '$usua'
AND status_pedido IN('ESPERANDO','APROBADO')";
```

> expr IN (valor, ...)
>
> Devuelve 1 si expr es igual a cualquiera de los valores en la lista
>   IN; de lo contrario, devuelve 0. Si todos los valores son constantes,
>   se evalúan de acuerdo con el tipo de expr y se ordenan. La búsqueda
>   del elemento se realiza mediante una búsqueda binaria. Esto significa
>   que IN es muy rápido si la lista de valores IN está formada
>   completamente por constantes.

Comment: Perfecto, gracias, ya acepto tu gentil respuesta..!

Comment: Tambien me dieron otra forma de hacer el query y fue esta: ` SELECT * FROM pedidos WHERE usuario = '$usua' AND (status_pedido ='ESPERANDO' OR status_pedido ='APROBADO')`

Comment: @JoseMHerreraV también es una buena opción, pero si deseas hacerlo dinámico y enviar esos estados como parámetro en un array, no tendrías que escribir tanto código y podría ser 1 estado, 2 estados...n estados; por lo contrario usando OR, tendrías que escribir la misma instrucción por cada estado

Answer (score 4):

Puedes utilizar el comando IN de esta manera:

```
AND status_pedido IN ('ESPERANDO','TERMINADO')
```

Referencia:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in

O utilizar OR, para ello también deberías agrupar las condiciones así:

```
AND (status_pedido = 'ESPERANDO' or status_pedido = 'TERMINADO')
```

Referencia:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_or

Answer (score 2):

Igual puedes tratar de este modo

```
$query = "SELECT * 
FROM pedidos  
WHERE usuario = '$usua
AND 
(status_pedido = 'ESPERANDO') OR
(status_pedido = 'APROBADO')";
```

> Usamos el operador `AND` para pedir que se umpla una segunda
>   condición, que a su vez esta dividida en 2 partes encerradas entre
>   paréntesis, donde primero indicamos que el status sea igual a
>   ESPERANDO y usando el operador `OR` después aclaramos que si no es
>   esperando puede ser aprobado y te debería funcionar también